# Pass dynamic HTML table script response from a PHP file to AJAX to a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem.
What I want to happen:
1. Create a pop-up div when a table field is clicked. (/)
2. Put items to pop-up div from a PHP file which echoes another table containing information. ( )
3. Help me. ( )

So I have this simple jQuery which handles the clicking of a certain table fields (particular the first column only) and inside it is an ajax request which sends and fetches data from schedule_class.php. But I wanted the echoes of schedule_class to be inserted in my div having light as an id.

MY AJAX SPLICE:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "schedule_class.php",
    dataType:"json",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data)
    {
         $("#pop").html().load('/sched_class.php');
    },
});
```

MY DIV

```
<div id="pop"></div>
```

SCHEDULE_CLASS.PHP

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
session_start();
$toggle = $_POST['toggle'];
$sub_code = $_POST['pe_code'];

if($toggle == 0)
{
    $_SESSION['pe_code'] = $sub_code;
    $response['status'] = $sub_code;

    echo // this echo should have been in the pop-up div
    '<table class="tbl_sched" align="center" style="position:absolute;width:95%;">'.
    '<thead class="tbl_sched_row_title">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:3px 20px"><b>'."CODE".'</b></td>
            <td style="padding:3px 50px"><b>'."SUBJECT".'</b></td>
            <td style="padding:3px 50px"><b>'."STUDENT".'</b></td>
            <td style="padding:3px 30px"><b>'."STUDENT#".'</b></td>
            <td style="padding:3px 15px; margin-right: 20px;"><b>'."COLLEGE".'</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbl_sched_row" style="height:inherit">';

...
...

?>
```

I am confident that it should have worked. But it didn't, I am wrong. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it `schedule_class.php`, or `sched_class.php`? Because you tell jquery to load `shed_class.php` on line `$("#pop").html().load('/sched_class.php');`

Comment: If you put "json" in dataType you must encode you echo from php.

Comment: @Seckin oh it's really schedule_php and I changed them, still not working

Answer (score 0):

You're telling jquery that you're expecting 'json' data in return but you're echo'ing a string of html, and you are also not using the `data` variable passed back from the php script to your `success` callback.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "schedule_class.php",
    dataType:"json",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data)
    {
         $("#pop").html(data.html);
    },
});
```

save the html string to a variable, then echo using `json_encode` ..../.php:

```
$html = 
    '<table class="tbl_sched" align="center" style="position:absolute;width:95%;">'.
    '<thead class="tbl_sched_row_title">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:3px 20px"><b>'."CODE".'</b></td>
            <td style="padding:3px 50px"><b>'."SUBJECT".'</b></td>
            <td style="padding:3px 50px"><b>'."STUDENT".'</b></td>
            <td style="padding:3px 30px"><b>'."STUDENT#".'</b></td>
            <td style="padding:3px 15px; margin-right: 20px;"><b>'."COLLEGE".'</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbl_sched_row" style="height:inherit">';

echo json_encode(array( 'html' => $html ));
```

Comment: hi thank you for answering but how if there are two variables I want to pass, $html and another $html_2, how do I do that with json_encode? :)

Comment: `echo json_encode(array( 'html' => $html, 'another_html' => $another_html ));` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the Echoed data from php then you can simple add the DATA to the html element like below

```
success: function(data)
{
     $("#pop").html(data.html);//if you echo the data normally(without JSON) then no need of '.html'
}
```